# SQL: Date Time UTC and Integer Conversion to Date in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Input:

| DateTime | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-18 21:36:41 UTC | 20200506 |
| 2020-12-19 20:35:41 UTC | 20200508 |

Output:

| DateTime | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-18 | 2020-05-06 |
| 2020-12-19 | 2020-05-06 |

Comment: Don't tag any old RDBMS; MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Google BigQuery, are all completely different products. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS; not 4 of them. Don't forget, as well, that when posting a question to *ask a question*, and show your attempts and explain why they didn't work or what about the research you performed that you didn't understand.

Comment: and when it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant, having their own functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only care about UTC dates, you can convert the values to dates and use `date_diff()`:

```
select date_diff(date(datetime), 
                 parse_date('%Y%m%d', date),
                 day)
```

This assumes that "date" is stored as a string.  If it is a number:

```
select date_diff(date(datetime), 
                 parse_date('%Y%m%d', cast(date as string)),
                 day)
```

If you care about the time zone (and often folks do), then you want to include that in the conversion to the date:

```
select date_diff(date(datetime, 'America/New_York'), 
                 parse_date('%Y%m%d', date),
                 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,DateTime_Col),CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date_Col))
FROM TAB
```

Comment: Will this work in BigQuery ?

Comment: No Idea - I tried this in SSMS

Comment: No Problem, thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work in BigQuery ?

In BigQuery you should use [`DATE(datetime_expression)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) function:

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) DateTime, Date
FROM src_table;
```